# Mysql query to get the row position in a table

Tags: mysql

I have table with id (store user id) and score in different match. I want what is the position of a user.

So for i try this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ff3e/25);
in this I am getting all the row but I need only user having id 3 and it position in the table.

like this:

```
Score  Postion
26        3
```

Even i try to do like this but no success

1. [MySql: Find row number of specific record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990420/mysql-find-row-number-of-specific-record)
2. [With MySQL, how can I generate a column containing the record index in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b787a/2

```
select * from (
select T.*,(@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rownum from (
select sum(score) as S,id from mytable group by id order by S desc ) as T 
JOIN    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
) as w where id = 3
```

Updated sqlfiddle and above query. Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

just add a where clause

```
select x.id,x.sum,x.rownum
from(
select id,sum(score) as sum,(@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rownum 
from mytable 
JOIN    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
group by id
  ) x
where id =3
```

Comment: ahh I missed that do a derived table

Comment: @adarnes: please check updated data in fiddle. query is not perfect: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ff3e/25

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT totalScore, rownum FROM (
    SELECT id,sum(score) AS totalScore,(@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rownum
    FROM mytable 
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    group by id) result
WHERE result.ID = 3;
```

Comment: same as other answer. i do not find any difference

Comment: I didn't see the other answer before posting - I was too impressed with SQL-fiddle (never used that before, very useful tool - thank you for sharing it!) to notice that other answers have been posted. 
Anywho, I do spot one difference, though - the selection here leaves out the ID, so it matches your initial question.

Comment: query is not perfect, missing somewhere. updated sql fiddle link :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ff3e/25